# Canvas breaks through page loads + cookies until quitting browser on windows chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

We have a canvas app which is persisting a problem across page loads all the way until chrome quits, with no errors.

What can persist across page loads even after we clear cookies, and are not using localStorage?

Specifically, we are drawing one canvas onto another via a `drawImage` operation. Commenting this out stops the problem.

We can no longer even draw a line into a new canvas until we quit the browser. Does not happen on latest OSX Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Windows Firefox.

Any ideas are extremely appreciated!

Comment: Please share some of the code (preferably a fiddle) so we can do some testing.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware, I realize it's a tough question to ask - looking for generic experiences with something as odd as persistence across browser sessions until quit as it's a bit of an emergency. Looking into reproducing a fiddle!

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware, the issue is a hardware acceleration bug in the current windows chrome which permanently mangles canvas on the tab. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bug in the current windows chrome caused by hardware acceleration.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=281738#makechanges